# SSIS Package Active Directory LDAP Query Failing if Not Run While Remoting Into Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory, ldap, sql-agent-job

I have a package querying our Active Directory based on this article by Dataqueen
http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/05/importing-data-from-active-directory-using-ssis/ .

I have two problems but i believe they related. The main problem I have is that I cannot get the package to run via a SQL Agent Job using a specific user that has been created to run the package via the job. The second is I (my user, which is admin basically everywhere) cannot run the package from the SSIS Catalog unless i remote into the server.

The package executes fine when I run it in BIDS. I then deploy the package to an SSIS Catalog on that server. I cannot execute the package in the SSIS Catalog from SSMS on my local machine but it works if I remote into the server and run it from SSMS there.

I have a service account user that has been created to run this package via the job. This account can run the package via the job but only if i set it admin on the server, i do not want to do this. I believe it has something to do with access to the required driver.

Why does it not work for me from my local machine and why does setting the service account to admin then allow it run the package via the job?

Apologies if this long winded and missing information, I am relatively new to this and this is my first posed question.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered what the problem was. The User did not have permission to access the required services. I thought it would automatically get access to the required but due to our group polices it has to specifically be granted.